# devp2p protocol: support for data compression?

Tags: protocol, devp2p

I am just wondering if the devp2p protocol, which is used for node to node communication, has support for data compression?

I am asking this, because it could be useful for faster block propagation within the network. Especially, when the tx count / block increases in the future.

So far, I haven't found a hint for it in:

- [https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ÐΞVp2p-Wire-Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol)
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/protocol.go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this came with snappy compression via EIP 706 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/706) - implementation in go-ethereum via https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/15106

Answer (score 3):

I had to dig around to find the hint that I was pretty sure existed :-)

It's in the Design Rationale document, under [Compression algorithm](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#compression-algorithm).

> The **wire protocol** and the database both use a custom compression
>   algorithm to store data. The algorithm can best be described as
>   run-length-encoding zeroes and leaving other values as they are, with
>   the exception of a few special cases for common values like sha3('').

The relevant code is in the [`go-ethereum/p2p`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/36a10875c8c1a34aab851e3f65da48ccbb5367ce/p2p) directory on GitHub.

I can't immediately see how the Wire Protocol code calls into where I assume the custom compression is implemented (which is either [`common/bitutil/compress.go`](http://compression/rle/read_write.go) or [`compression/rle/read_write.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ac93a6ff6cd1200ab0fb67a5bd0c02cb70646632/compression/rle/read_write.go)?), and there are actually some calls in the RLP code to [Snappy](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/23ac78333201890deed23576668810e19df2c67e/p2p/rlpx.go#L604) (Google's compression library).

Perhaps further investigation is required to be sure...

Comment: Okay, @ligi's answer gives you the hard facts :-) Mine just waffles on.

Comment: I wish, I could mark both as a valid answer, but since ligi was faster, he's getting the +15 bonus. :-).

Comment: Actually AFAIK RLP and Snappy are the only compressions algorithms used in devp2p/rlpx. Any clues on what the Compression Algorithm section in your find is referring to?